# Retrieve data from screen to screen in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

Im sending the data "item.email" from screen X to screen HomeParent
How can I retrieve the data in the HomeParent screen?

```
  renderItem=(item,index)=>{
    return(
       <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeParent",item.email)}>
            <View style={styles.listItemTitleContainer}>
              <Text>Hello</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as a object field

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeParent",{mail:item.email})}>
```

and use getParam like this,

```
const email = this.props.navigation.getParam('mail')
```

Comment: I can use getParam in the all class? Or do I have to write in the componentDidMount function?

Comment: @user123456 No need to write in component didMount func. The param will be passed as a prop to your component so it will accessible by your prop in the class